# Cards not getting aligned correctly

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to have four cards.I want first two cards be horizontally aligned next to each other and then two cards need to be below and also to be aligned horizontally next to each other.

I am using two separate `LinearLayout` each for a row of two cards(i.e two cards in each row).

**The problem is that only first two cards are visible and other two cards are not visible.**

> XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#bcd4d4"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        android:layout_width="180"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="15dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#52bf90"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:onClick="missed"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="MISSED"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            >

        </TextView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        card_view:cardElevation="15dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#52bf90"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:onClick="received"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="RECEIVED"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            >
        </TextView>

        <!--/>-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view3"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"

        card_view:cardElevation="15dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#52bf90"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:onClick="dialled"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="DIALLED"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            >
        </TextView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view4"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"

        card_view:cardElevation="15dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#52bf90"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:onClick="stats"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="STATS"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            >
        </TextView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `LinerLayout`'s orientation to `horizontal` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

> **Like this below.**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
```